# Is it possible to find the absolute value of an integer using only elementary arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic, absolute-value

Using only addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and "remainder" (modulo), can the absolute value of any integer be calculated?

To be explicit, I am hoping to find a method that does not involve a piecewise function (i.e. branching, `if`, if you will.)

Comment: Note that there are two common definitions of remainder: I believe computer programs typically define $a \% b$, for $b>0$, to be between $-b+1$ and $0$ when $a \le 0$, and between $0$ and $b-1$ when $a \ge 0$. Whereas mathematicians would typically prefer to define $a \% b$ to be between $0$ and $b-1$ always (if they define $\%$ at all, which they typically don't). I'm not sure what a programming language would typically do in the $b \le 0$ case.

Comment: If integer division is acceptable (as implemented in major programming languages, i.e. rounding towards zero), then I would suggest `(3*x / (3*x-1) * 2 - 1) * x`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:
$$m=n\%(n^2-n+2)\\
p=m\%(n^2+2)\\
|n|=2p-n$$

If $n\ge0$ then $m=n$ and $p=n$.
If $n<0$ then $m=n^2+2$ and $p=0$.

Comment: Nice use of $n^2 > 0$. There may be a problem if n = -1.

Comment: Pretty good, but it doesn't work for n = 0 or -1

Comment: Your latest edit nailed it. Awesome :)

Comment: I think $|n|=m\%(n^2+n+2)$, which saves a step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with no.

My (not super rigorous) proof would be that any function of the variable $x$ using only addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division would have to be a differentiable function on its domain, but $|x|$ is not a differential function on all of its domain, and its domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

The introduction of an expression like $(x\mod 4)$ would introduce points of discontinuity (and hence not differential), but it would introduce an infinite amount of them (at all multiples of four), and the function $|x|$ only has one point of not being differentiable (at $x=0$).

Comment: No. |x| is continuous. It is not differentiable (at 0).

Comment: Oops my bad, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772348/get-absolute-value-without-using-abs-function-nor-if-statement.

Please note that remainder is modulo, absolute is modulus, so please correct the question, because I can't suggest edit.

Comment: Bitwise operations would work on a computer but I was looking for something that didn't delve into that realm.

Comment: OK, I got it! :)